# Set selected tab bar item tint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am aware there are similar answers on this topic, but I cant seem to come to any conclusion. I'm using IOS 8 and a tab bar created in app delegate. Is there a way to set the selected tab bar item to a certain colour. preferably without using an image. [image: id like to replicate this if possible]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor myBlueishColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor myBlueishColor]];
```

You may find more related information here: 
http://jslim.net/blog/2014/05/05/ios-customize-uitabbar-appearance/

Comment: Do you call it before the actual tabbar is displayed? `didFiishLaunchingWithOptions` is a good place.

Comment: Tried in viewDidLoad. If didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is right place then updating your answer with such information will make it more clear.